# Selected CCMenuItemToggle cocos2d-x

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

My code:

```
 CCMenuItem *soundItem = CCMenuItemImage::create(
                                            "menu/and_sound.png",
                                            "menu/and_sound.png",
                                            this,
                                            NULL );
    CCMenuItem *soundOnItem = CCMenuItemImage::create(
                                            "menu/and_soundon.png",
                                            "menu/and_soundon.png",
                                            this,
                                            NULL );

    CCMenuItemToggle* soundMenu = CCMenuItemToggle::createWithTarget(this,NULL,soundItem,soundOnItem,NULL);
    soundMenu->setPosition(ccp(550,66));
    this->addChild(soundMenu,1);
```

Button appear normally but when I press it don't change state and image to selected state.

Comment: both images are same  that's why change does not effect .

Answer (score 1):

I know it may be too late now, but for anyone who is still searching answer:

Instead of

```
this->addChild(soundMenu,1);
```

use CCMenu and add soundMenu in CCMenu.

Answer (score 1):

heres a working code example, you forgot to use CCMenu

```
CCMenuItem *itemOn = CCMenuItemImage::create("on.png", "on.png", this, NULL);
CCMenuItem *itemOff = CCMenuItemImage::create("off.png", "off.png", this, NULL);

CCMenuItemToggle* itemToggle = CCMenuItemToggle::createWithTarget(this, NULL, itemOff, itemOn, NULL);

CCMenu* menu = CCMenu::create(itemToggle, NULL);
addChild(menu, 1);
```